# Apache Pig: Can we convert a custom Writable object to Pig format?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

We have a SequenceFile of custom Writable Values objects, the object essentially equate to a complex bag data type in Pig.

Is there a convenient way that we can write a custom function to convert the hadoop Writable object to a bag data type and then process it using a pig script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to look at [elephant-bird](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird#pig-support) - if you scroll down this github page to the README section, it has a section about Pig:

> Pig
>
> - Includes converter interface for turning Tuples into Writables and vice versa

I've never used it, and i imagine you'll have to implement some code yourself (probably an extension of the [`com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.util.WritableLoadCaster`](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/pig/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/util/WritableLoadCaster.java) abstract class and the [`SequencedFileLoader`](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/pig/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/load/SequenceFileLoader.java) to load your sequence file using your load caster implementation

Comment: A converter should be implemented for the custom writable. 
There's a good example in the elephantbird/mahout subproject (`VectorWritableConverter`).

Comment: It's interesting. We'll try it and tell you if we have success. Thanks!